# How to use Spring JPA query name convention to query wildcard

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA query name convention for querying database. It really provide a great way to query and save me a lot effort. Below is one example i used to query by name and sex.

```
public interface SysUserRepository extends CrudRepository<SysUserEntity, Integer>{
   SysUserEntity findByUserNameAndSex(String name, String sex);
}
```

It works fine but I don't know whether it support querying by wildcard. For example, I want to search all men whose name start with "Z". How can I use above method to do that query for me? So I want to write something like below to do the query:

```
  findByUserNameAndSex("Z*", "male")
```

Whether JPA support that kind of query?

Comment: Wondering if it supports it? Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Try with WHERE name LIKE ’Z%’

Comment: `findbyUserNameLikeAndSex` should do the trick. Or `findByUserNameStartsWithAndSex`.

Comment: you could use custom @Query or look at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation , for example -> StartingWith findByFirstnameStartingWith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Query like that:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM table c WHERE c.sex = :sex AND c.name LIKE CONCAT(:name, '%')");
query.setParameter('sex', sex);
query.setParameter('name', name);
```

Comment: Why not use advantage of Spring Data's query creation or query annotation ?
In my opinion, it's shorter to write, read and understand

Comment: I answered this in 2016 @NayoR I was not in touch with this future +1 from me as well ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the date, it just popped on Top Questions because you edited it !

Answer (score 2):

Refering to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), you can use "StartingWith":

```
SysUserEntity findByNameStartingWithAndSex(String name, String sex);
```

This corresponds to:

```
@Query("select su from sysuser su where su.name like ?1% and su.sex = ?2")
```